# Automatic close quotes on Xcode

Tags: xcode

Is there any way to have a second double quotes placed automatically, when I enter the first one in Xcode? There aren't any settings in Xcode regarding placing a second double quote automatically when entering the first one (like in VSCode eg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the autocompletion work.

i.e.Type print then autocomplete to print(items: Any...) then press " 
or ^"

take a look at this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/TextCmdsByType/TextCmdsByType.html